# react native firebase How to check if chatroom already exist

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I would like to check if chatroom already exist. and I don't want to make another chatroom with the same person. I searched it a lot and I found this code but it didn't work for me. I can make a lot of chatroom with the same person.

[same chatrooms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUDUR.png)
like that

[image: firebase data]

firebase data

if you help me I'd really appreciate it.

```
  const userChatRef = db
    .collection('chats')
    .where('users', 'array-contains', user.email);
  const [chatsSnapshot] = useCollection(userChatRef);
  const makeRoom = () => {
    if (user.email !== email && !chatAlreadyExists(email)) {
      db.collection('chats')
        .add({
          users: [user.email, email],
        })
        .then(doc => {
          navigate(MESSAGEROOM, {id: doc.id, recipientEmail: email});
        });
    } else {
      alert('Already exist!');
    }
  };
  const chatAlreadyExists = recipientEmail => {
    !!chatsSnapshot?.docs.find(
      chat =>
        chat.data().users.find(userEmail => userEmail === recipientEmail)?.length > 0,
    );
```

Comment: Is that your code or is this the code from the internet? could you please give more information how you chatdata is stored?

Comment: @FlorianPürschel I uploaded the picture. all docs the same data 
dd@naver.com,bb@naver.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you currently can't have more than one `'array-contains'` statements in a firebase query. I would suggest to simply do the following:

```js
const checkForDuplicateChat = (userid1, userid2) => {
    const db = firebase.firestore()
    // fetching all chats of bb@naver.com
    // userid1 = e.g. bb@naver.com
    let chats = db.collection('chats').where('users', 'array-contains', userid1).get()

    // mapping the parsed json data in the array
    data = data.docs.map(el => el.data())

    // el.users.length === 2 to check if it is a chat existing only
    // between user1 and user2 (excluding groupchats etc.)
    // userid2 = f.e. dd@naver.com
    data = data.filter(el => el.users.length === 2 && el.users.includes(userid2))

    if(data.length > 0) return // what ever happens when there already is a chat

    createChat(user1, user2)
}
```

I hope this helps at first, but keep in mind you will have a ton of reads when all users have a lot of chats, because you always have to fetch all the chats of the user before filtering out.

**EDIT:**
You also could add an Array to the document of each user, which lists all other users he has a chat with like:

```
bb@naver.com:{
    mail: "bb@naver.com",
    hasChatWith: [
        "dd@naver.com",
        "cc@naver.com",
        "ee@naver.com"
    ]
}
```

So in this case you just have to check the array `hasChatWith` of bb@naver.com before he opens a chat. If you open a new chat make sure you add **both** users to eachothers list.

Comment: Is there a way to read less than this? if all users have a lot of chats.

Comment: As alternative you could do what I added to my original answer above.